# Show that in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ every absolutely convergent series converges.

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ every absolutely convergent series converges.

My try:

Take some absolutely convergent series in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$. Then we have:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Vert f_n\Vert = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n|\ \mathrm{d} \lambda = \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n| \ \mathrm{d} \lambda <\infty.$$
This can be true only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n (x)| <\infty $ for $\lambda$-almost all $x$. As $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n (x)| $ is a monotone series in $\mathbb{R}$, it now has to be convergent.

For a series in $\mathbb{R}$ we know that absolute convergence implies convergence. So now we can define $F(x):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ for $\lambda$-almost all $x$, and assign to $F$ some arbitrary value for all the other $x$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^m f_n\to F$ pointwise for $\lambda$-almost all $x$, which means that
$$\Vert \sum_{n=0}^m f_n-F\Vert = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\sum_{n=0}^m f_n-F|\ \mathrm{d}\lambda \to 0,$$
so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ is a convergent series.

Is this proof correct? I'm not sure about reversing integration and summation at the beginning. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is mostly okay, until the end.

You say "I'm not sure about reversing integration and summation at the beginning" - whenever you say this, that means you have to prove it more carefully!  The linearity of the integral only lets you interchange limits with *finite* sums, so you can't just rely on that.  In this case you can use the monotone convergence theorem: if you let $S_m = \sum_{n=0}^m |f_n|$, then $\{S_m\}$ is a monotone increasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions, converging pointwise to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n|$.

At the end there is a big gap, where you have the words "which means that".  Showing that $\sum_{n=0}^m f_n \to F$ pointwise is definitely not enough by itself to imply that $\int \left|\sum_{n=0}^m f_n - F\right| \to 0$.  Surely you know lots of sequences which converge pointwise but their integrals don't converge to the integral of the pointwise limit.  There is a fair amount of work still to do here.

Comment: To fill the big gap, could we maybe apply Dominated Convergence, as $|\sum_{n=0}^m f_n|\leq \sum_{n=0}^m |f_n|\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n|$? Then I would still need to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n|$ is integrable, but this follows from the Monotone Convergence statement I need to prove the integration/summation-reversal at the beginnning, right?

Comment: @user161518: Yes, something like that should work.

Comment: Great! Then concerning this Monotone Convergence statement. Can we in fact say that $\sum_{n=0}^m |f_n|\to \sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n|$? Because we don't yet know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n(x)|$ is finite for all $x$ right? Or doesn't it have to be finite at all?

Comment: @user161518: If you read the MCT carefully, it doesn't require the limit function to be finite.

Comment: Okay, so you can apply MCT to every monotone sequence of measurable functions?

Comment: @user161518: They also have to be nonnegative.